# Not able to play videos with JMF

Tags: java, maven, video, jmf

I am learning how to play videos using JMF from [this](http://underpop.online.fr/j/java/help/playing-video-and-other-media-with-java-media-framework-multimedia-applets-and-applications.html.gz#ch21table06) link.

It throws:

```
Unable to handle format: MPEG, 1280x720, FrameRate=23.9, Length=1382400 
Failed to realize: com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@659a969b 
Error: Unable to realize com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@659a969b 
javax.media.CannotRealizeException at 
javax.media.Manager.blockingCall(Manager.java:2005) at 
javax.media.Manager.createRealizedPlayer(Manager.java:528) at 
com.mycompany.mavenproject3.MediaPanel.<init>(MediaPanel.java:33) at 
com.mycompany.mavenproject3.MediaTest.main(MediaTest.java:47) 
Could not realize media player
```

The `MediaPanel`:-

```
  import java.awt.BorderLayout;
  import java.awt.Component;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.net.URL;
  import javax.media.CannotRealizeException;
  import javax.media.Manager;
  import javax.media.NoPlayerException;
  import javax.media.Player;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;

  public class MediaPanel extends JPanel
  {
   public MediaPanel( URL mediaURL )
  {
   setLayout( new BorderLayout() ); // use a BorderLayout

   // Use lightweight components for Swing compatibility 
   Manager.setHint( Manager.LIGHTWEIGHT_RENDERER, true );

    try
   {
   // create a player to play the media specified in the URL 
   Player mediaPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer( mediaURL );

   // get the components for the video and the playback controls 
   Component video = mediaPlayer.getVisualComponent(); 
   Component controls = mediaPlayer.getControlPanelComponent(); 

   if ( video != null ){
   add( video, BorderLayout.CENTER ); 
   }

   if ( controls != null ){
   add( controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH ); 
   }

   mediaPlayer.start(); // start playing the media clip
   } // end try
   catch ( NoPlayerException noPlayerException )
   {
   System.err.println( "No media player found" );
   } // end catch
   catch ( CannotRealizeException cannotRealizeException )
   {
   System.err.println( "Could not realize media player" );
   } // end catch
   catch ( IOException iOException )
   {
   System.err.println( "Error reading from the source" );
   } // end catch
   } // end MediaPanel constructor
   } // end class MediaPanel
```

My MediaTest.java file:

```
  import java.io.File;
  import java.net.MalformedURLException;
  import java.net.URL;
  import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
 
  public class MediaTest{

  public static void main( String args[] )
 {
 
 JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

 
 int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog( null );

 if ( result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) // user chose a file
 {
 URL mediaURL = null;

 try
 {
 
 mediaURL = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toURL();
 } 
 catch ( MalformedURLException malformedURLException )
 {
 System.err.println( "Could not create URL for the file" );
 } 

 if ( mediaURL != null ) 
 {
 JFrame mediaTest = new JFrame( "Media Tester" );
 mediaTest.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

 MediaPanel mediaPanel = new MediaPanel( mediaURL );
 mediaTest.add( mediaPanel );

 mediaTest.setSize( 300, 300 );
 mediaTest.setVisible( true );
 } 

 } 
 } 
 }
```

My pom.xml file:-

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject3</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmf</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1e</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.conviva.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>conviva-mediaplayer-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>2.145.0</version>
            <type>aar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

When I try to run the code, A popup appears which allows me to choose the video file I want to play, but when I choose the file, It says:- "Could not realize Media PLayer."

I am trying to play mpg format videos(mpg format is supported by JMF). I have to tried to play other video formats also like-mpeg,au etc but they are also not playing.

I have searched a lot on the web, while there are similar posts stating they were facing the same issue but there were not any clear solutions to this problem. I am attaching a pic of the issue I am facing.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Note:- I am allowed to use only JMF for making this Video Player.

Comment: 1) Replace each `catch ( ..Exception ex) { ..` with `catch ( ..Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); ..` and report back. 2) JMF is old. Its support for new CODECs (formats) stopped being updated long ago, so it does not support many modern video types.

Comment: Unable to handle format: MPEG, 1280x720, FrameRate=23.9, Length=1382400
Failed to realize: com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@659a969b
Error: Unable to realize com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@659a969b
javax.media.CannotRealizeException
 at javax.media.Manager.blockingCall(Manager.java:2005)
 at javax.media.Manager.createRealizedPlayer(Manager.java:528)
 at com.mycompany.mavenproject3.MediaPanel.<init>(MediaPanel.java:33)
 at com.mycompany.mavenproject3.MediaTest.main(MediaTest.java:47)
Could not realize media player @AndrewThompson

Comment: Better to [edit] the question to add stack traces. I did that with this one. As to the problem with the MPEG - it's a container format AFAIR, which means the content video can have many different encodings. JMF will play some MPEGs, but not others.